# When do two equations represent the same line in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The question states that if $\mathbb U\neq0$ and $\mathbb V\neq0$ then complete the sentence :

> The equations $$\mathbb X=\mathbb X_o + t\mathbb U$$ $-\infty<t<\infty$
>
> and $$\mathbb X=\mathbb X_1 + s\mathbb V$$ $-\infty<s<\infty$
>
> represent the same line in $\mathbb R^n$ if and only if. . .

Can anyone explain how to go about this? I was thinking of stating that $\mathbb X_o$ is a multiple of $\mathbb X_1$ and that $\mathbb U$ is a multiple of $\mathbb V$ but I don't think this is the correct way to go about it. I have to prove this conversely as well since this is a biconditional but I'm not sure how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$X_1$ must satisfy the first equation, i.e. $X_1-X_0$  and $U$ must be colinear, and the direction vectors $U$ and $V$ must be  colinear too.